# Cast Collection Value Type

Tags: c#

I have a collection of type `Collection<Lookup<int>>` and I would like to convert its values to `Collection\Lookup<int?>>.`  What's the best way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Which lookup are you talking about?  The one I know about (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) takes 2 type parameters, not one.

Comment: It's a proprietary Lookup class.

Comment: Can you post the code for the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Collection.ObjectModel.Collection<T>` is related to `IEnumerable<T>` you should be able to use the `Select` extension method.

Something along the lines of:

```
var listOfNullables = lookupsAsInt.Select(l => new Lookup<Int?>(l.Value)).ToList();
```

You'll need to include `using System.Linq;` in your class file.

Comment: I wasn't including `using System.Linq;`  Adding that made all the difference.

Comment: This won't work for converting Collection<Lookup<int>> list to a Collection<Lookup<int?>>.

Comment: @BrentAnderson - Feel free to downvote. The only value the OP got out of this answer was figuring out that they needed to include a using statement to System.Linq. The *answer* part of the answer is the last line. I'll update it to reflect the correct answer

Answer (score 4):

Well, a Lookup is a collection of keyed IEnumerables; basically a read-only `Dictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>>`. A `Lookup<int>` is nonsensical.

Probably the best way to tackle this would be to "de-group" each item from the Lookups into an anonymous key-value pair with a nullable value, then re-group the items.

Example:

```
var myCollectionOfNullableInts =
   (from g in MyCollectionOfIntLookups
   from v in g.Values
   select new {g.Key, Value = (int?)v}
   into l
   group l by l.Key into g2
   select g2).ToList();
```

The resulting collection SHOULD be a `List<Lookup<[your key type], int?>>`.

Comment: The collection is of type System.Collections.ObjectModel and for some reason none of the Linq methods (extension methods) are coming up in the intellisense.  I'm scratching my head.  I'll try to restart VS.  Thanks.

Comment: As your marked answer indicates, make sure you are referencing the System.Linq namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Lookup<T>` has a constructor that takes some value `T` *and* a property called Value that returns the T in question....

```
var lookupsAsNullableInt = lookupsAsInt.Select(l => new Lookup<Int?>(l.Value)).ToList();
```

The thing is, you'd need to know how to construct a single new `Lookup<int?>` from a single `Lookup<int>`.  Then the above code does the work of transforming an enumeration of one into a List of the other.

Comment: I think you're missing a ?. Otherwise doing a projection from one type to another is correct.

Comment: Right, had it backwards.  Thanks Chris.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming members A,B,C, this will convert the original collection to a new `Collection<Lookup<int?>>` and test the first value.

```
        var nowNullable = new Collection<Lookup<int?>>(lookup.Select(l => new Lookup<int?> {A = (int?) l.A, B = l.B, C = l.C}).ToArray());
        nowNullable.First().A = null;
        Console.WriteLine(nowNullable.First().A.HasValue);
```